# Binary search two unsigned integers

Tags: c, binary, binary-search, unsigned, signed

A function which inputs two unsigned integers a and b and finds whether the lowest byte of b appears exactly as it is in a (starting at any position) or not. ex:

```
    Enter a:53
    Enter b:13
    Binary of b: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001101
    Binary of a: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00110101
    Yes, lowest byte of b appears in a.
```

GUYS this is my home work but i cant do it pls help me thank you for your helping

Comment: You shouldn't be posting homework here - how about telling us what you've tried, and what doesn't work, and maybe we can help point you in the right direction

Comment: This is not what would normally be called "binary search".

Comment: This is off-topic asking for 'Please do my homework' and doesn't belong on SO

Comment: i'm new.i dont know exactly what i do

Comment: Look up the `>>` (shift right) and `&` (bitwise and) operators.

Comment: @KontDooku Please try adding any code that you have tried to use to solve this yourself already. SO is not a homework completion service, you need to show that you have put in some effort yourself already and what point you are stuck at in particular.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some pseudo-code to get you started:

```
found = FALSE
for shift = 0 to 24
    if least significant byte of a == least significant byte of b then
        found = TRUE
        break
    endif
    shift a right by 1 bit
endfor
```

Now all you have to do is turn this into C code.